# Strange row issue

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need a little help with an issue I got while I was trying to add rows to my table.

I have this code:

HTML:

```
 <table class="dataTable" id="CADataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Type</th>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Adress</th>
        <th> ID Number</th>
        <th> Contact</th>
        <th> Note</th>
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>        
        <td><input type="text" name="CAType" style="width: 9em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CAName" style="width: 15em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CAAdress" style="width: 15em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CAIdNum" style="width: 6em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CAContact" style="width: 10em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CANote" style="width: 15em;"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="export" class="button" onClick="test()">ADD</button>
```

and JQUERY:

```
test = function(){
       $('#CADataTable tr:last').after('<td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>');
};
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ngvk/)

The first row is added correctly and everything is ok, but after pressing the button again, the 2nd row is not showing where I was expecting it. I also tried this:

```
$('#CADataTable > tbody:last').append('<td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>');
```

without success. I'm sure that I'm missing something really small, but as a jquery beginner I'm not able to spot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you forgot to add the `tr` element. Add `<tr></tr>` to your jquery code. Like this...

```
$('#CADataTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 4):

append to `tr` not to the `tbody`

```
$('#CADataTable tbody tr:last').append
```

If you want to append it as a row

```
$('#CADataTable tbody').append('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/9Ngvk/2/

Answer (score 1):

Include `<tr>` tag in `after` method. Like below

```
$('#CADataTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');
```